# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

i'm currently using sails.js and i deploy it in a2hosting shared hosting with turbo plan , i'm trying to connect to the sails socket in (ionic /angular) app i used the nodejs script for sails.io.js and socket.io.js from this documentation [from here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js) 
and this is my configuration in my ionic app

```
    this.io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
    this.io.sails.url = 'https://example.com/api';
    this.io.sails.path = '/api';
    this.io.sails.environment = 'production';
    this.io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;
```

and every time trying to connect this errors appear

```
websocket.js:110 WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/api/?__sails_io_sdk_version=1.2.1&__sails_io_sdk_platform=node&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

any one can help me please ?

Comment: I'm not sure if `url` and `path` are real, are they? I logged `io.sails` in console and it gave me undefined for `url` and `path` - https://i.imgur.com/DSPYnTT.png

Comment: yeah the path and url is not real it's just for example ,

Comment: you can test this it's 
    this.io.sails.url = 'https://martstations.com/api';
    this.io.sails.path = '/api';

Comment: I mean that does `io.sails` support options for `url` and `path`?

Comment: yes it's support this options you can check this from here   : https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/sails-socket/properties